# ConstantScoreRangeQuery is not giving correct results for ip range queries

Tags: lucene, ipv6, ipv4

I am using `ConstantScoreRangeQuery` for searching all IP addresses of range where range is `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`.  This is pretty much searching all IPv4 addresses.

I am converting all my IP addresses to strings and indexing them.  For example, `0.0.0.0` becomes `00000000` and `255.255.255.255` becomes `ffffffff` where every 2 chars are one octet.

When I am searching for IP addresses, I am creating a query as follows:
`ConstantScoreRangeQuery(fldIdStr, "00000000", "ffffffff", true, true)`

I am storing both IPv4 as well as IPv6.  This query returning IPv6 as well.

I am using Lucene (lucene-core-2.4.0.jar) 2.4.0;

How can I get only IPv4 addresses within an IP range.

Answer (score 0):

> I am converting all my IP addresses to strings and indexing them

This approach is wrong. [Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreRangeQuery.html) of `ConstantScoreRangeQuery` says:

> This query matches the documents looking for terms that fall into the
>   supplied range according to String.compareTo(String). It is not
>   intended for numerical ranges, use NumericRangeQuery instead.

There's no way you can query IP ranges with `String.compareTo(String)`.

You need to index IP addresses as numbers and define the logic by which you define what does it mean to be in (and out of) given range.

On top of that, `ConstantScoreRangeQuery` is deprecated and has been removed in version 3. You **really** have to upgrade to a newer Lucene version (v4.0 is out now).

Comment: I may be missing something in my answer.  Why can't you compare IPv4 addresses with String.compareTo?  To my thinking, lexicographic ordering should work just fine for comparing two hex numbers of guaranteed equal length.

Comment: And how exactly would you compare ipv4 address against ipv6 address? Also, don't forget there is CIDR notation and integer notation, e.g. http:// 2915189354 (remove the space to get the link working)

Comment: Yes, there is significant complexity to comparing IP addresses without a specified notation, but given that the OP has eliminated CIDR, integer, and even dot-decimal notation by guaranteeing a format (simply 8 hex digits), the only issue becomes eliminating IPv6 results, right?

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Wanted to be sure of my thinking on that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [TermRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TermRangeQuery.html) with a custom [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) passed as a sixth arg to the constructor.

Simply implement a Collator, String.compareTo should work fine for comparing IPv4 addresses formatted as you have specified, unless there is something I'm missing.

To eliminate IPv6 matches, you could first check length, return a positive or negative result as appropriate for non-zero length differences, and if the lengths are equal, only then return the result of String.compareTo.

Another option, if it is feasible to change your index format slightly, you could prefix stored values with the IP version, such as: `v4ffffffff` or `v6ffffffffffffffff`.  In that case, as long as you consistently apply that prefix to each value and query, a standard TermRangeQuery with the arguments you stated should do the job nicely.